# How to derive the differential equations of motion for a dumbbell system ,eg. dumbbell satellites around earth?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, celestial-mechanics, astrodynamics

From Eq. 2.13 from [Orbital Mechanics for Engineering Students](https://www.elsevier.com/books/orbital-mechanics-for-engineering-students/curtis/978-0-12-374778-5) (Curtis, 2005) the equation of relative motion between two bodies orbiting around a center of mass can be written as:

$$\ddot{\mathbf{r}} = \frac{\mu}{r^3} \mathbf{r}$$

where

$$\mu=G(m_1+m_2).$$

How would you obtain the same for a dumbbell system. A dumbbell system consisting of point masses at the ends of a rigid massless tether rotating around its center of mass, in in-plane motion about the Earth.

It would be very helpful to see the equation of motion derived for a rigid body mentioned in the question involving translational motion and rotational motion.

Comment: This question is difficult for me to understand, what is it you are really asking? How do you know this equation? Where did it come from? Also, "What are equations of motion (in celestial dynamics)?" is probably a separate question, but you'd probably have to show some independent work of some sort. Try to narrow down to one specific and clear question only. You can ask many questions; break them up a bit. But maybe wait for one answer before asking the follow-up.

Comment: I've fixed the MathJax adding vectors where they belong and changed $\dot{\mathbf{r}}$ (velocity) to $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}$ (acceleration). I would recommend you ask first for orbit around a large point-mass instead of the oblate, lumpy planet Earth. Also, if you've tried to solve this, even a little bit, your question will be better received if you explain what you've tried so far, or what might be holding you up. Just asking "solve this problem for me" may not get a complete answer.

Comment: This really feels more like a theoretical physics question than spaceflight. Is there a practical application of crunching numbers for a dumbbell system with a massless tether that I'm overlooking?

Comment: @Saiboogu This question is about orbital mechanics and is certainly on-topic here. There is no theoretical physics, just basic engineering (forces, torques, dynamics, etc.). If you think about it, standard [Gravity gradient stabilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity-gradient_stabilization) of spacecraft is already a non-rotating, asymmetric "dumbbell". An answer will contain some insight into spacecraft dynamics that could be applied elsewhere, perhaps for artificial gravity or tethers or something else.

Comment: Well, I guess you just convinced me to cast the deciding vote on reopening. It seems better fleshed out from the original.

Comment: @uhoh Thank yo very much for re-writing and helping with the question being presented in a better way and thank you for the explanation. :)

Comment: @CJSpitzer great! So is it OK for the answer to just treat the Earth as a central force, and ignore the higher order multipole terms like oblateness (J2) etc.? It can be asked as a follow-up question if you need it, but leaving them out for now makes it much easier to answer this quesiton.

Comment: @uhoh It is very much okay. I agree that the initial problem should be simplistic to solve. :)